# How to create a pendulum with spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a pendalum in spritekit but i cannot figure out how to make the pendalum swing. So far the code is:

```
transparentpixel = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"transparent_pixel"];
[transparentpixel setPosition:CGPointMake(150,150)];
transparentpixel.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
transparentpixel.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
[_bg addChild:transparentpixel];

pendalum = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pendalum_image"];
[pendalum setPosition:CGPointMake(150,120)];
pendalum.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:pendalum.size];
pendalum.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
[_bg addChild:pendalum];

CGPoint pendalumjointanchor = CGPointMake(150,150);
SKPhysicsJointPin *pendalumJointPin = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:transparentpixel.physicsBody bodyB:pendalum.physicsBody anchor:pendalumjointanchor];
[self.physicsWorld addJoint:pendalumJointPin];
```

I can't figure out how to make the pendalum swing indefinetely.

Comment: Have you tried applying force to the pendulum? AFAIK Sprite Kit doesn't have motor forces for joints. And FYI you don't need a transparent pixel sprite node to anchor the joint, just create a plain SKNode as the invisible anchor for the pin. That will be more efficient.

Comment: How can i apply force to the pendalum? I can swing the pendalum left-right with rotateToAngle SKAction if the transparent pixel's dynamic property is set to NO. If i set it to YES the pendalum won't swing. It just rotate left-right. Somehow i have to make the transparent pixel static so that only the bottom part of the pendalum image swing.

Comment: Actions don't move physics bodies, meaning they don't apply forces to the bodies. With a physics body all movement should be done through force/impulse/velocity, not actions. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsBody/applyImpulse:

Comment: You may also be able to use the new (in iOS8) SKFieldNode to act as a restorative force at one or both ends of the pendulum, that way you don't have to have code watching the position of the pendulum so that it can know when to apply a force/impulse/velocity.

Answer (score 0):

You can create physics bodies on each side of the pendulum around where the pendulum would reach it's max height.

Set an event to trigger when the pendulum hits these physics bodies.  In this event, Apply a downward force.

After playing with the physics bodies locations and the amount of force, you should be able to achieve something very similar to the effect you are after.